# How to use Java to determine if the machine I am running in is using ipv4 or ipv6?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp, ipv6

I need to return 0.0.0.0 for the bind IP of an UDP socket in Java. But I am not sure if I should return "0.0.0.0" (ipv4) or "::" (ipv6) for the host of my socket. Can I always return "0.0.0.0" and it will work? Or should I have to first find out if the machine I am running on is ipv4 or ipv6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> need to return 0.0.0.0 for the bind IP of an UDP socket in Java.

Why? Just use an `InetAddress` of `null.` It means the same thing, but it is IP-version-agnostic.

Comment: That makes sense, but in this case I really need to return a STRING describing 0.0.0.0, no matter what IP version I am using.

Comment: @PeterMel Return it from what? What is it you're trying to describe? and what exactly do you mean by 'will it work'? Work with what? And what's wrong with the result of `DatagramSocket.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress()`?

Comment: Will it work means: "If I give a host of 0.0.0.0 to a socket object running on an IPV6 machine will it work as expected or I must pass "::" instead ?

Comment: @PeterMel Why? The constructors concerned take an `InetAddress`, not a `String.`